# Message "Timed out waiting for launcher to connect " visual studio code (Python)

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

i have a message appearing in vscode when i run the program in python saying "Timed out waiting for launcher to connect". Afterwards, i tried to install some extensions like python for VScode but it didn't work. here is my configuration at this link [config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6vaf2.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. [Please don't post screenshots of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/354577). They can't be searched or copied, or even consumed by users of adaptive technologies like screen readers. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your question. If you select it and click the `{}` button or Ctrl+K the code block will be indented by four spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, ensure that the python extension is installed successfully, and then delete this launch.json file.

Then click like picture:

[image]

[image]

[image]

It will automatically generate launch.json files that match your environment.

You can refer to this [document](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/debugging) for more details about debugging